# Position absolute inside list element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position some list's element based on the viewport but they ultimately stick to their parents.

To reproduce the issue, I just need to create a list with an element positioned absolutely :

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  list-style: none;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="element">
      <p>
        Element
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, the element isn't positioned at the top left of the viewport but, instead, relatively to the `ul`.

Am I missing something ? Could it be the static position of the `li` elements ?

Comment: *absolute* is relative to a *positioned* element...add `position: relative` to the `li`...

Comment: It only make the element's position relative to the li, not to the viewport.

Comment: try this and look at the behavior of the 

**.element {
  position: absolute;
  top: -40;
  left:200;
  background-color: red;
}**

Comment: The top and left styles doesn't apply themselves unless I add 'px' and the end, and the position is still incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `position: fixed` instead. `position: absolute` will position an element absolutely relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (in this case your `ul` with `position: absolute`), while `position: fixed` will position an element relative to the viewport*.

Code snippet:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  list-style: none;
}

.element {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="element">
      <p>
        Element
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

* There are some exceptions to this, for example a `transform` on an ancestor will break this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you want make the element's position relative to the viewport, parent(`ul`)  should not have `position:absolute`, So:

Method 1) remove `position: absolute` of `ul`:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

ul {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  list-style: none;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="element">
      <p>
        Element
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Method 2) change in html code :

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  list-style: none;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <!--Other Content -->
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="element">
      <p>
        Element
      </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm upvoting your response since the given solutions works. Unfortunately, I cannot remove the `position: absolute` from the `ul` nor change the HTML due to other restrictions. FYI : @Jesse de Bruijne 's solution is the one I was looking for, using fixed positions instead of absolute ones.

Comment: @ThomasFerro, thankyou for upvote.but if you set `position:fixed` for element,it fixed and dont move when scroll page.use of  `body { height: 2200px;}` and scroll page and see result.

Comment: This behavior suit me well in this specific case, since my application has a body width and height set at 100% and each component manage his own overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Remove `position:absolute` in `ul` class and give `position:relative`. and `body` and `ul` element have default margins set on them. so remove it.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin:0;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin:0;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="element">
      <p>
        Element
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```